# Dark box instead of custom tabBar item

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

I'd like to display a custom tabBar item (or an empty space) in my storyboard but no matter what I try it's just showing a dark box instead of the item:

[Image of TabBar Controller with Dark Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yU61h.png)

I have not made any programmatic changes to the tabBar & as you can see, the default iOS items appear normally. Cheers!

**Edit**: Here's what I've tried until now:

- Adding "Bar Item" title in Storyboard (SB) **=** Dark box with no text
- Choosing a "Selected Image" for the "Tab Bar Item" in SB **=** Dark box
- Choosing an "Image" for the "Bar Item" in SB **=** Only shape visible + no color

[Image of Current Attribute Inspector State](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfBQt.png)

Comment: Start sharing your tries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want an empty tabBar without any function or action, then just set the `Title` and `Image` in the `Attributes inspector` of this Tab Bar Item empty. Everytime you delete an existing title or image value confirm with hitting Enter/Return. The last part is to uncheck the `Enabled` checkbox, so hitting the empty space has no effects.

**See the screenshot:**

[image]

**Result:**

[image]